# Am I required to do anything if suggestion is made to move question?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762325/deleting-code-and-unit-tests-in-java) and the comments suggest that it should be moved to [programmers.stackexhange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Is the onus on me to move the question?

Comment: I've reviewed the question, but I'm not going to move it, since it's already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question cannot be migrated by regular members, you should flag your question for moderator attention. We will determine if your question really is a better fit for Programmers, and migrate it if so.

Be sure not to [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info); that is generally frowned upon on Stack Exchange sites, especially in the case of answered questions where answers can become fragmented or duplicated.

If your question is not moved, chances are it was deemed unsuitable for the other site.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Just for clarity: so the onus is on me to flag my own question or can anyone do it?

Comment: @bated: Anyone with the ability to flag questions can do it.